# How to stop ts-lint complaining about my created classes in a file and classes created in other files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I have put the following statement at the top of my file in Visual Studio Code:

```
// @ts-check
```

I have ESLint 2.1.23 in my extensions.

I create a class in my javascript `MessageQueue` which has a member which is another of my classes called an `OrderedListARR` which is defined in another file. This is the code:

```
MessageQueue = function () {
    this.m_ARR = new OrderedListARR();
};
```

This is how it looks in Visual Studio Code:

[image]

When I hover over `MessageQueue` it says **Cannot find name `MessageQueue`** and similarly for `OrderedListARR`.

How can I overcome this so ts-lint recognises these are **real honest** things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading about importing/exporting, e.g. [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) and [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) which are both supported by NodeJS (and most browsers support ESM if you tag your scripts as such). You can Google on how exactly use ESM in both and how to use CommonJS in the browser (probably by bundling), but CJS should work by default in Node.js using `require('module')`.

Simply explained, one file e.g. `something.js` looks like this:

```js
module.exports.SomeClass = ...;
```

And your other file looks like this:

```js
const { SomeClass } = require('./something');
```

*those examples use CJS, ESM would use a different syntax*

That's for importing classes you define in other files.

Your second problem seems to be that you're defining `MessageQueue` without using `const`/`let`/`var`. When you're declaring a brand new variable, you need to use e.g. `let someVar = ...;`. You didn't, hence ESLint complains. For classes, you should also be able to use the [class syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). In that case, simply doing `class ClassName { ... }` automatically counts as using `var`.